# Query optimization: EXPLAIN outputs millions of rows for view

Tags: mysql, optimization

When I run:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM my_view
```

There is a "derived2" table there that has > 600 million rows:

[image: explain view]

Now, if I try to the EXPLAIN the select inside the view (the actual "SELECT" our view is made of), I get the exact same structure, except the  huge table:

so:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM [contents of the view itself]
```

[image: explaining the select inside the view]

None of my tables have more than 1200 rows, so I'm wondering why am I getting the > 600 million from.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: Ask another question that includes the query that generates the view.  That is the only way to know how it is generating so many rows.

Comment: OK, maybe I didn't make myself clear. We have a view: "Create view my_view as select * from table ...", and if i thrown an "Explain select * from my_view", I get everything you see in the first screenshot, but if i go "explain select * from my_table ..." (which is exactly the same query that makes the view), I get everything I see in the second screenshot